# How to add the height of the container when adding to listview in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview, layout, flutter-listview

I want to make a dynamic height listview, meaning when add a new item in listview, the the container of the listview should add height.

For example, when adding to listview, the container is 100, add new item container from 100 to 150, etc.

#### My code

item listview

```
Widget listviewItem({
  required Map model,
  required BuildContext context,
}) =>
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Container(
        height: 56,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            containerBoxShadow(),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
            children: [
              Text(
                'title item',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(
                flex: 3,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/icons/edit_icon.png'),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: const Color(0xffC08832),
              ),
              pSizeboxWidth10(width: 5),
              IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/icons/remove_icon.png'),
                onPressed: () {
                  DatabaseCubit.get(context).deleteData(id: model['id']);
                },
                color: const Color(0xff505F6D),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This function builds a listview on the screen:

```
Widget listeviewBuilder({
  required List<Map> item,
  required BuildContext context,
}) => Expanded(
        flex: 8,
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => listviewItem(
            context: context,
            model: item[index],
          ),
          itemCount: item.length,
        ),
      ),
```

This in the main screen:

```
CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              // this padding between border of screen and container
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10,
                  left: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  bottom: 35,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      containerBoxShadow(),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(pCardBorderRadius),
                  ),
                  height: 600,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                      ConditionalBuilder(
                          condition: DatabaseCubit.get(context)
                              .newList
                              .isEmpty,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => Spacer(),
                          fallback: null,
                        ),

                        // depot items
                        listeviewBuilder(
                          context: context,
                          item:
                              DatabaseCubit.get(context).newList,
                        ),
                        ConditionalBuilder(
                          condition: DatabaseCubit.get(context)
                              .newList
                              .isEmpty,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => Spacer(),
                          fallback: (BuildContext context) =>
                              pSizeboxHeight20(),
                        ),

                        // this for add item
                        Container(
                          child: elevatedButton(
                            width: 213,
                            height: 36.24,
                            name: 'Add new item',
                            onPressed: () {
                              // When pressed, open popup menu and add a new item for listview
                              popupDialogWidget(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        pSizeboxHeight20(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the height of the Container widget that has the ListView.builder() in it. The Container widget will automatically expand to fit the size of its child.

```
CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              // this padding between border of screen and container
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10,
                  left: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  bottom: 35,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      containerBoxShadow(),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(pCardBorderRadius),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                    ConditionalBuilder(
                        condition: DatabaseCubit.get(context)
                            .newList
                            .isEmpty,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Spacer(),
                        fallback: null,
                      ),

                      // depot items
                      listeviewBuilder(
                        context: context,
                        item:
                            DatabaseCubit.get(context).newList,
                      ),
                      ConditionalBuilder(
                        condition: DatabaseCubit.get(context)
                            .newList
                            .isEmpty,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Spacer(),
                        fallback: (BuildContext context) =>
                            pSizeboxHeight20(),
                      ),

                      // this for add item
                      Container(
                        child: elevatedButton(
                          width: 213,
                          height: 36.24,
                          name: 'Add new item',
                          onPressed: () {
                            // when pressed open popup menu and add new item for listview
                            popupDialogWidget(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      pSizeboxHeight20(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
```

I haven't tried this code, but I think it's going to work fine.

Comment: no bro it doesn't work the console give me that (The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.)